# How to get all product name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

This Code Show Only one product name i need all product name

```
 global $woocommerce;
foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {

            $productname = get_the_title($values['product_id']);



}
```

help me.....

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through the products in the cart and overriding the variable `$productname` each time.

So outside of the loop it will always be set to the last one.

Create an array of product names instead, or just echo it directly. It depends on your use case.